# How do I make class method user type guard work in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make a user type guard defined inside a class instance method work, I'm using latest typescript 4.0.5, and can't find a way to fix it. I'm getting an error (commented below). Here's the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFEA8EMFsAcA2BTUB3AlgFwBagMaLQDOxosyuA9gCagCuxyATqFgJ7yoDm90zNAFCESZAIIBvQaAJUAdsSzN6%20LFWYAKePQBGiDPlBy4yAPwAuUIuYY53AJQSAvtNDa9B0DhIA5ExvtLXAwyENAJYwpLa1tuJykZGWZKemY5IxNQAEIAXhyGORpkADNbZBoAblcXF2F5RVB9RTFQfIBtOWQ0UDENAHIAKSocOT77ABojLp6Ayc7u3r6AWX4AazGAXQA6UsQsFg1oVoA%20UGgt72I-CgD7OoUqFC3EKm4NJqwxNoAGbcjkLZqACq8C4zAAwiRkLdBIIQBAYAgUOhsHhivQ5KoMPIGExWBwuKBePwhMIiKRQAAhBKyBRKFRqTTufSGf4WKxKWKOGr3BqXa6ofIaHSWSmBUA6UBhCImaKcuxOE4ZCjZPIFIqlTqVWH4epYRohLCU1qgDrTSn9IYjMZzc2zKbdC3LNabHYYPYHfkmexVXUPJ4vN4fSk-P4mQFUEFgyFMGGCIA).

```js
// Example with class method user type guard
class A{
  constructor(public name?: string){}
  public hasName(): this is {name: string}{
    return name !== undefined;
  }
}

const listA = [new A('John'), new A(), new A('Mark')].filter(a => a.hasName())
console.log(listA[0].name.toUpperCase()) // Error: Object is possibly undefined

// Example with function user type guard

class B{
  constructor(public name?: string){}
}
const hasName = (b: B): b is {name: string} => name !== undefined;

const listB = [new B('John'), new B(), new B('Mark')].filter(hasName);
console.log(listB[0].name.toUpperCase()) // No error, type guard makes Typescript know it can not be undefined
```

Comment: It has to do with the arrow function.  If you replace `hasName` in the list B filter with `b => hasName(b)` then you get the same issue, even though that one's not a class method.  But I'm not sure how you get around it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are aware, [one of the call signatures](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/135c5082b19f6a3f664cd737e569acd6e87fb852/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1355) of the `Array<T>.filter()` method in the standard TypeScript library will narrow the type of the returned array's element when you pass in a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) function as its parameter:

```
 interface Array<T> {
   filter<S extends T>(
     callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => value is S, 
     thisArg?: any
   ): S[];
 }
```

The `hasName()` function is a user-defined type guard, and that works.

But when you call it with `a => a.hasName()` instead, the type of that function is inferred to return just `boolean`.  That's because user-defined type guard functions do not propagate and are not inferred for you; see [microsoft/TypeScript#10734](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10734).  A type like `x is Y` generally gets widened to `boolean` by the compiler as soon as you start doing things with it.

You could tell the compiler that your arrow function callback is also a type guard by using an arrow-function return type annotation, like this:

```
const listA = [new A('John'), new A(), new A('Mark')].filter(
  (a): a is A & { name: string } => a.hasName()
);
console.log(listA[0].name.toUpperCase())
```

Note that the type predicate is `a is A & {name: string}` instead of just `a is {name: string}`.  That's because, strictly speaking, a type predicate must *narrow* the value in question, and `{name: string}` is not a subtype of `A` (since `{name:string}` is missing the `hasName()` method).  You can apparently get away with `this is {name: string}` in a method because polymorphic `this` is not checked as strictly in a type predicate (as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#5906](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/5906)).  Anyway, the intersection `A & {name: string}` fixes it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-kriMCkWCIU64QizMiqGiMdimHiCUA)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work, I tried something similar, but ended up going for Omit<A, 'name'> & {name: string}, which was too cumbersome to be considered usable, but that is good enough.

It's a shame that type guards don't propagate, I end up having to re-define the typeguard each time I want to use it.

Comment: Follow up question, does it even make sense to define the type guard in the class method instead of making it return boolean?

Comment: If you're ever going to call it directly on an object and use it in the same scope, then yes, it serves the same purpose as any type guard.  If you're only ever passing it to `filter()`, maybe not.  Note that you could make the operation of "turn an unbound type guard method into a type guard function" generic so that instead of annotating manually you call something like `myList.filter(bindGuardMethod("hasName"))`, but that's only worthwhile if you're planning to do that a bunch of different times.  Anyway both of these scenarios are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/nWPP5W) if you care

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense, I'm probably going to do this a bunch of times, so it might make sense to have this helper